# How to reset left time of user systemd timer

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

How can I reset the left time of a user systemd timer?

I have a user systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remind to a take break

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/scripts/break_reminder
Environment=PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/scripts

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and a user systemd timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Remind to a take break

[Timer]
OnStartupSec=0min
OnUnitActiveSec=30min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Edit:
Restarting the timer both by restart and stop + start isn't reseting the left time.

```
$ systemctl --user status break_reminder.timer 
● break_reminder.timer - Remind to take break
     Loaded: loaded (/home/adam/.config/systemd/user/break_reminder.timer; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-05-30 16:19:00 CEST; 3h 48min ago
    Trigger: Sun 2021-05-30 20:24:05 CEST; 16min left
   Triggers: ● break_reminder.service

May 30 16:19:00 archadam systemd[383]: Started Remind to take break.

$ systemctl --user restart break_reminder.timer
$ systemctl --user status break_reminder.timer 
● break_reminder.timer - Remind to take break
     Loaded: loaded (/home/adam/.config/systemd/user/break_reminder.timer; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-05-30 20:07:24 CEST; 1s ago
    Trigger: Sun 2021-05-30 20:24:05 CEST; 16min left
   Triggers: ● break_reminder.service

May 30 20:07:24 archadam systemd[383]: Stopping Remind to take break.
May 30 20:07:24 archadam systemd[383]: Started Remind to take break.

$ systemctl --user stop break_reminder.timer  
$ systemctl --user status break_reminder.timer
○ break_reminder.timer - Remind to take break
     Loaded: loaded (/home/adam/.config/systemd/user/break_reminder.timer; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2021-05-30 20:07:32 CEST; 1s ago
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● break_reminder.service

May 30 20:07:24 archadam systemd[383]: Stopping Remind to take break.
May 30 20:07:24 archadam systemd[383]: Started Remind to take break.
May 30 20:07:32 archadam systemd[383]: break_reminder.timer: Deactivated successfully.
May 30 20:07:32 archadam systemd[383]: Stopped Remind to take break.

$ systemctl --user start break_reminder.timer 
$ systemctl --user status break_reminder.timer
● break_reminder.timer - Remind to take break
     Loaded: loaded (/home/adam/.config/systemd/user/break_reminder.timer; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-05-30 20:07:39 CEST; 2s ago
    Trigger: Sun 2021-05-30 20:24:05 CEST; 16min left
   Triggers: ● break_reminder.service

May 30 20:07:39 archadam systemd[383]: Started Remind to take break.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnUnitActiveSec` binds to the last activation time of `break_reminder.service`.

> OnUnitActiveSec=
> Defines a timer relative to when the unit the timer unit is activating was last activated.

([systemd.timer manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html))

So to reset the left time on `break_reminder.timer`, you'd need to reset the last activation timestamp of `break_reminder.service`.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to reset this timestamp except by actually starting the service unit. (`systemctl set-property` isn't able to change the timestamp and it is neither affected by `systemctl reset-failed`, `systemctl clean` nor by `systemctl daemon-reexec`).

Answer (score 1):

Restart the service:

```
# systemctl restart break_reminder.timer
```

and see whether this works.

If it does not try force-restarting:

```
# systemctl stop break_reminder.timer
# systemctl start break_reminder.timer
```

and let us know.

Comment: It's not working. I added the info to my question.